# Android App link is not verified when wild card domains are used

Tags: android, applinks

This is my `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
 <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="https" android:host="*.example.com" />
 </intent-filter>
```

This is my `assetlinks.json`

```
{
   "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
   "target": {
      "namespace": "android_app",
      "package_name": "com.example.main",
      "sha256_cert_fingerprints": ["256 sha256_cert_fingerprints"]
   }
}
```

This is how app links verified page looks like when the app is installed,

[image]

which means link is not verified automatically. But when I mentioned `sandbox.example.com` in `AndroidManifest.xml` then link is auto verified as soon as app is installed.

Do wild card domains also auto verified? If so, Am I doing something wrong with my configuration?

Note: Here I am using `example.com` since I don't want to show actual domain?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39616895/how-to-implement-android-app-links-with-wildcard-domains/49918919#49918919

Comment: yes I am using example.com in host and it works

Comment: @KamalNayan Are you using `*.example.com` in host and able to open your app by clicking on `sandbox.example.com`?

Comment: @inkredusk I have gone through that post already. But they didn't use any wildcard domains

Comment: @ThinkAndCode yes

Comment: @KamalNayanDid you place assetslinks.json in https://example.com or https://www.example.com?